# ORACLE 'INSERT ALL' WHEN UNIQUE THEN...for one of the INTO clauses and ELSE... for the other

Tags: sql, sql-insert, oracle12c

I am trying to use `Insert all` to do

```
insert into temp_table 
select distinct id, name from member_table;

insert into member_data_table
select * from member_table;
```

So technically it should be

```
insert all
into temp_table(id, name) values (id, name)
into member_data_table(all_cols) values (all_cols)
select * from member_table;
```

But I'm not sure how to make sure I only get unique members hence the (**Distinct**) as part of a `Insert ALL`. Is it a possible at all and if it is, how would I do it(maybe with a `Case When`??? but how).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One approach to insert distinct records in one table but not another is to make use of `INSERT ALL`'s row-level conditional insert-control.

By attaching differentiating `WHEN` conditions to `INSERT`s against `TEMP_TABLE` and `MEMBER_DATA_TABLE`, you can limit to distinct `INSERT`s on one and not the other.

But, if it is not totally necessary to use `INSERT ALL`, it may be preferable to consider just executing two `DML` statements, for its advantageous readability and simplicity.

Anyway, here's an example that only `INSERT`s distinct (`ID + NAME`) into `TEMP_TABLE`, but all data into `MEMBER_DATA_TABLE`:

Create the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_TABLE(ID INTEGER, NAME VARCHAR2(32));
CREATE TABLE MEMBER_TABLE(ID INTEGER, NAME VARCHAR2(32), OTHER NUMBER);
CREATE TABLE MEMBER_DATA_TABLE(ID INTEGER, NAME VARCHAR2(32), OTHER NUMBER);
```

Load duplicated `ID + NAME` into `MEMBER_TABLE`:

```
INSERT INTO MEMBER_TABLE  VALUES (1,'A',1000);
INSERT INTO MEMBER_TABLE  VALUES (2,'B',2000);
INSERT INTO MEMBER_TABLE  VALUES (1,'C',3000);
INSERT INTO MEMBER_TABLE  VALUES (1,'C',4000);
INSERT INTO MEMBER_TABLE  VALUES (1,'C',5000);
COMMIT;
```

Then execute the `INSERT ALL`:

```
INSERT ALL
    WHEN ID_NAME_SEQ = 1 THEN INTO TEMP_TABLE(ID, NAME) VALUES (ID, NAME)
    WHEN 1 = 1 THEN INTO MEMBER_DATA_TABLE(ID, NAME, OTHER) VALUES (ID, NAME, OTHER)
SELECT ID, NAME, OTHER,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, NAME ORDER BY OTHER ASC) AS ID_NAME_SEQ
FROM MEMBER_TABLE;

8 rows created.
```

And query the results:

```
SELECT ALL ID, NAME FROM TEMP_TABLE ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC;

  ID NAME
   1 A
   1 C
   2 B

SELECT ALL ID, NAME, OTHER FROM MEMBER_DATA_TABLE ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC, 3 ASC;

  ID NAME     OTHER
   1 A         1000
   1 C         3000
   1 C         4000
   1 C         5000
   2 B         2000
```

Comment: This is great...thank you!...My intention was to be more efficient. So...I want to use an INSERT ALL to avoid having to loop through around 65 tables(each with thousands of rows of data to be copied) twice....Not sure if it is more efficient but that's my theory right now. I agree with you... 2 DML's would be better for readability and simplicity.